# notepad++ - create udl which is a modified version of xml language

Tags: notepad++

In notepad++, I want to create udl which is a copy of xml but instead of tags `<...>` and `</...>`, I want the tags to be `<#...#>` and `<#/...#>` for opening and closing folds.

#### Why I need it

The reason is that there are lots of places where `<` is used (as a less than sign for example) and this messes up the folds. For eg - if I add a code snippet `if val < 10` then xml thinks this is the beginning of a fold and this messes up the folds everywhere in the document from that point.

#### What I did

I created a udl. I added to it a 'Folding in code 1 style' with values of 'Open:" = `<#`, 'Middle:' = `>` and 'Close:" = `#>`. Also I added a styler to make 'Foreground color' = 'red' (as it is in the xml language).
Note - This udl doesn't exactly duplicate tags inside xml but this is the best I could do based on my understanding of the udl documentation.

#### What works

with above setting, the tags itself (ie `<#`, `>`, `#>`) are red (as desired)

#### What doesn't work

if I create `<# text_inside_tag >` then I want the 'text_inside_tag' to be red as well (this is what it is in xml language) but I can't get it to work.

#### What I ideally want

I want to but can't create a UDL that works exactly like xml language but only with these modified tags `<#...#>` and `<#/...>`. In xml, the text inside the tags ie between `<...>` and `</...>` is red in color.

#### What I might be ok with

if my above problem in the 'What doesn't work' section of creating red text here `<# text_inside_tag>` is fixed, that would be ok as well (but not ideal).

I hope this clarifies the question.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you read the guide? https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/user-defined-language-system/ what happens when you create a language file? What did you put in it? What happened? What did and did not work? We can help you solve specific problems implementing a solution but we need you to tell us where in the process you are stuck.